# How to access the global variable from event listener in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, event-listener

I have one Angular project which uses fabric.js for canvas.
I have one problem in using event listener to the canvas object.

In the code below, I want to use the global variable "disabled" in the function "movehandler".
"console.log(this.disabled)" does not work.
It is shown as "undefined" in the console.

How can I use global variable in the function for canvas.

```
...
disabled = "yes";
...

ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.canvasTerm);
    console.log(this.canvas);
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
    this.canvas.setHeight(this.innerHeight - 120);
    this.canvas.setWidth(this.innerWidth - 120);
    this.canvas.on('object:moving', function () {
        console.log('Event object:moving Triggered');
    });

    var moveHandler = function (evt) {
        var movingObject = evt.target;
        //console.log("sss",movingObject.get('left'), movingObject.get('top'));
    };

    //handler for done modifying objects on canvas
    var modifiedHandler = function (evt) {
    var modifiedObject = evt.target;
    console.log(this.disabled);
    console.log( modifiedObject.id,"last",modifiedObject.get('left'), modifiedObject.get('top'));
    };

    var customEvtHandler = function (evt) {
        console.log("I was triggered by a custom event.");
    };

    //or you register with key/value pairs
    this.canvas.on({
        'object:moving' : moveHandler,
        'object:modified' : modifiedHandler,
        'custom:event' : customEvtHandler
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try arrow function.

instead of:

```
function (evt) {
}
```

try this:

```
() => {
}
```

or

```
(evt) => {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var scope = this;
var modifiedHandler = function (evt) {
    var modifiedObject = evt.target;
    console.log(scope.disabled);
};
```

Or using arrow function:

```
var modifiedHandler = (evt) => {
    var modifiedObject = evt.target;
    console.log(this.disabled);
};
```

**Note: You should not use `var` everywhere, use `let` instead for variables which are used only in a block. `var` should be used for global variables.